# Visual Studio seems to have lost the link between corresponding aspx/aspx.cs files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, csproj

I am encountering a rather pesky issue with a C# script that I'm writing in Visual Studio. The whole thing was working fine, but all of a sudden, it seems VS has 'forgot' to link the aspx and aspx.cs files (all references to the aspx-file are suddenly not recognized anymore).
For example:

```
    In ASPX:
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="RegisterHyperLink" ViewStateMode="Disabled">Register as a new user</asp:HyperLink>

In corresponding aspx.cs:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register";
```

In the .cs-file, VS claims that RegisterHyperLink does not exist in current context. Before, this was just working fine, yet the same kind of stuff happens in other places/files as well.
I already checked the references, and checked this site, where it was suggested that maybe the .csproj-file was corrupted (with the compile-statement not including the files). This, however, seems not to be the case, as the compile-statements match the aspx and aspx.cs-files in the correct order.
What could be the problem?

Comment: At the top of the aspx page should be a line that looks like this: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyPage" Codebehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" %>` - on your pages, do the `Inherits` and `Codebehind` attributes reference the right class and file? This can sometimes get messed up by text auto-formatters

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible reasons for this:

1. `YourPage.aspx.designer.cs` has been deleted, or excluded from the project somehow. If it has been deleted, you can repair it by highlighting `YourPage.aspx` in the solution explorer, then click the Project menu followed by Convert To Web Application.
2. The `<%@ Page...` directive at the top of your aspx page is wrong, and points to the wrong or missing file.
3. `YourPage.aspx.designer.cs` still exists, but is not being updated by Visual Studio when you make changes to `YourPage.aspx`. You can remedy this by editing the designer file yourself, and adding the appropriate field declaration for `RegisterHyperLink`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It turned out some namespaces were edited and they did not match the <%@... directive anymore (i.e. option 2 in your reply).